# Storing authentication tokens in DB

Tags: security, authentication, restful-authentication

I have a unique authentication token per client, of which all tokens are stored in a server database.  As this is effectively a password, providing access to all of the logged in user's data, I assume that it'll need obscuring in the DB somehow.  Does anybody have any advice on doing so, please?

I would imagine that either of the following options are secure enough, but does one have more cons than pros?

1. Encrypt the token for storage and decrypt during authentication using a private key stored in a protected file on the server.
2. Get the client to create and store a unique key, then use it to hash the DB token stored on the server and send it with every request, meaning the token is only valid if it can be verified with the unique key.

Based on my limited knowledge, option 2 seems to be the most secure, so is there an accepted way of doing this?  I'm vaguely aware of how this process might work, but would struggle to put it into practice, so any links to blog articles you may be aware of would be awesome!

Thanks!